# How to deploy gnosis safe proxy contracts on Mumbai testnet(Polygon) using Safe Core SDK?

Tags: metamask, gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I am following Safe Core SDK [docs](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk) and wants to create a safe proxy contract on the Mumbai testnet, getting the following error `Error: Invalid Safe Proxy Factory contract address` when I switch to Mumbai/Ropsten testnet in the Metamask after [instantiating](https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/build/sdks/core-sdk#2.-deploy-a-new-safe) SafeFactory class. This error does not occur when I switch to Rinkeby testnet(Ethereum) or some other ethereum testnet. Can some please tell me how to deploy a safe on Mumbai testnet using safe core SDK?

I am using [Safe Core SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk#sdk-api) v1.1.1 and [web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3) v1.6.1 for instantiating the ethAdapter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Safe Core SDK takes all the safe contracts and network configuration from [safe-deployments](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments/). Specifically on this case, from [here](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.3.0/gnosis_safe_l2.json), meaning that if the Mumbai chainId (80001) is not present below the  `networkAddresses` key, the Safe contracts are not deployed in that network.

When that happens, you need to deploy the contracts manually. Once deployed, the Safe Core SDK offers the possibility to use Safe contract instances from networks that are not supported in `safe-deployments`. This can be done this way:

```
import { ContractNetworksConfig } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk'

const chainId = await ethAdapter.getChainId()
const contractNetworks: ContractNetworksConfig = {
  [chainId]: {
    multiSendAddress: '<MULTI_SEND_ADDRESS>',
    safeMasterCopyAddress: '<MASTER_COPY_ADDRESS>',
    safeProxyFactoryAddress: '<PROXY_FACTORY_ADDRESS>'
  }
}

const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter, contractNetworks })
```

Where `MULTI_SEND_ADDRESS`, `MASTER_COPY_ADDRESS` and `PROXY_FACTORY_ADDRESS` are the addreses of your recently deployed Safe contracts in Mumbai network.

Now you can create a new Safe with your `safeFactory` instance:

```
const safeSdk = await safeFactory.deploySafe(safeAccountConfig, safeDeploymentConfig)
```

When instantiating the Safe Core SDK to be used with an unsopported network, you will always need to use this same `contractNetworks` parameter the same way:

```
import { ContractNetworksConfig } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk'

const chainId = await ethAdapter.getChainId()
const contractNetworks: ContractNetworksConfig = {
  [chainId]: {
    multiSendAddress: '<MULTI_SEND_ADDRESS>',
    safeMasterCopyAddress: '<MASTER_COPY_ADDRESS>',
    safeProxyFactoryAddress: '<PROXY_FACTORY_ADDRESS>'
  }
}

const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress, contractNetworks })
```

Find here the latest documentation regarding the [SafeFactory](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#safe-factory-api-reference) and [Safe Core SDK](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#safe-core-sdk-api-reference) API references with all the optional params

Comment: Thanks, [German](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/89118/germ%c3%a1n).