# Error in deploying a safe - methods is empty

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am writing a simple script to deploy a safe, using the safe-core-sdk. I faced multiple issues that I have bee resolving but currently there is a point where I am stuck.

*issue 1* CommonJS vs ES6 import/export
In order to use the `Web3Adapter` I had to use like `new Web3Adapter.default`. An explanation on why can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs)

*issue 2*  Contract Networks mandatory for not supported networks.
Since I am using a ganache testnet for my local development as described [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/116770/how-to-deploy-gnosis-safe-proxy-contracts-on-mumbai-testnetpolygon-using-safe) I deployed the Multisend contract and Mastercopy (and the others) in my local tesnet.

*issue 3* `TypeError: this.contract.methods[methodName] is not a function`
After the `safeFactory` is created I am trying to use to deploy a Safe

```
const safeSdk = await safeFactory.deploySafe({
    safeAccountConfig,
    safeDeploymentConfig,
});
```

However, I get the error from above, looking through the code it reads froma  methods which indeed is empty. I have deployed de contracts on my tesnet so no idea how to sort this one out.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Github issue created to fix *issue 1*: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/issues/243

After our videocall, *issue2* and *issue3* were fixed by specifying the correct ABIs in the `contractNetworks` argument. The docs have been updated to reflect this properly.

Thank you!