# Trying to deploy a gnosis safe multisig wallet with 3/5 threshold on mumbai testnet

Tags: gnosis-safe, polygon, gnosis

I am trying to deploy a gnosis safe multisig wallet with 3/5 threshold on mumbai testnet. I try and launch it using their website interface but apparently it does support mumbai mainnet but not mumbai testnet for some weird reason. Can anyone guide me how to have that exact interface but for mumbai testnet.

Comment: Clone their github and deploy by your own.

Comment: which repo do i have to clone exactly ?

Comment: I think this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/116770/how-to-deploy-gnosis-safe-proxy-contracts-on-mumbai-testnetpolygon-using-safe) have what you are looking for.